# Criteria not working as intended - retriving from two tables

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two classes which are associated with each other as `OneToOne`

```
User {
  int user_id
  @OneToOne 
  UserAccount useraccount 
  Role role;
}
```

```
UserAccount {
  int useraccount_id
  @OneToOne
  User user;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve a list of UserAccount where User role does not equal manager. The following is the query I set up and I can't get it working.

```
Criteria userCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
            userCriteria.add(Restrictions.ne("role", Role.MANAGER));
            userList = (List<User>) userCriteria.list();
```

It retrieves a list of User.class object ignoring the restriction.

Comment: What SQL you see in consol?

Comment: What's the structure of `Role`? Is it enum?

Comment: @Orthodox & @hamed It was a mistake from me. Its working as intended. I kept checking the wrong request page. One thing I like to do, is take the column of `User` called `Role` and join it with columns of `UserAccount`. Is the only way to do this by creating a temporary object object to hold `user.getRole()` and `username.getUserAccount_id`, `useraccount.getName` etc? I only need one column from `User` object.